# Magento Custom Module in CMS Page Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cms, cms-block

I am trying to create a custom module and enabling it in a CMS Page.

I've already done this before and everytime some issue comes up and I could figure this out anyhow.

I couldn't figure out what's the issue this time. Below are the code that I've been trying to make it work.

```
**app/etc/modules/Vickythegme_CMS.xml**

<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Vickythegme_CMS>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Vickythegme_CMS>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Module config XML

```
**app/code/local/Vickythegme/CMS/etc/config.xml**

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>  
        <Vickythegme_CMS>  
            <version>0.0.1</version>  
        </Vickythegme_CMS>  
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <vickythegme_cms_render>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Vickythegme_CMS</module>
                    <frontName>tryon</frontName>
                </args>
            </vickythegme_cms_render>
        </routers>    
        <layout>
            <updates> 
                <vickythegme_cms>
                    <file>vickythegme_cms.xml</file>
                </vickythegme_cms>
            </updates>
        </layout>  
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <vickythegme_cms>
                    <class>Vickythegme_CMS_Block</class>
                </vickythegme_cms>
            </blocks>
        </global>
    </frontend>


</config>
```

Design Layout XML File

```
**design/frontend/base/default/layout/vickythegme_cms.xml**

<layout version="0.1.0">
 <default>
  <reference name="content" />
</default>
<vickythegme_cms_render_index_index>
 <reference name="content">
  <block type="cms/tryon"  name="tryon_tryon" template="cms/tryon.phtml" />
</reference>
</vickythegme_cms_render_index_index>
</layout>
```

Block tryon.php file

```
**code/local/Vickythegme/CMS/Block/tryon.php**

class Vickythegme_CMS_Block_Tryon extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
 public function methodblock()
 {
     return 'testing block';
 }
}
```

Controller File

```
**code/local/Vickythegme/CMS/controllers/IndexController.php**

class Vickythegme_CMS_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function methodAction()
    {
        echo 'test method';
    }
}
```

tryon phtml file

```
**design/frontend/base/default/template/vickythegme/cms/tryon.phtml**
test content
```

I've cleared the cache and tried as well. Its not working.

The url that I am checking

http://magento-15667-34663-87261.cloudwaysapps.com/try-on

try-on is the CMS Page that I created with the block code

```
{{block type="cms/tryon" name="tryon_tryon" template="cms/tryon.phtml"}}
```

And the page url that I should be checking directly gives me 404 error.

http://magento-15667-34663-87261.cloudwaysapps.com/tryon/index

And btw, I've enabled logging, still I don't get any error in the log related to this module.

I'm not even sure whether the module is running or not.

I'm not sure what's happening. If you guys could help me out in this issue, it'd be really awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your block type is `vickythegme_cms/tryon` and not `cms/tryon`.
And your template is `vickythegme/cms/tryon.phtml` and not `cms/tryon.phtml`.

You block must be nammed `Tryon.php` and not `tryon.php`.

Also you need to allow your block under System > Permissions > Blocks if you're running Magento 1.9.2.2.

Also your config xml `global` tag is not place properly, it should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>  
        <Vickythegme_CMS>  
            <version>0.0.1</version>  
        </Vickythegme_CMS>  
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <vickythegme_cms_render>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Vickythegme_CMS</module>
                    <frontName>tryon</frontName>
                </args>
            </vickythegme_cms_render>
        </routers>    
        <layout>
            <updates> 
                <vickythegme_cms>
                    <file>vickythegme_cms.xml</file>
                </vickythegme_cms>
            </updates>
        </layout>  
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <vickythegme_cms>
                <class>Vickythegme_CMS_Block</class>
            </vickythegme_cms>
        </blocks>
    </global>

</config>
```

Comment: Hi, @digital-pianism, Thanks for the reply. I tried that one as well.. It's not working. Any other places where I go wrong?

Comment: Yeah try changing your layout handle from `<vickythegme_cms_render_index_index>` to `<tryon_index_index>`

Comment: That's not working either.! And I'm guessing that won't be a problem because that is for showing the page directly and I'd atleast need the try-on CMS Page to work which is related to your first comment and sadly that's not working either.

Comment: What's the content of your phtml file ?

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: I changed my config.xml file and that's not working either. The content in the phtml file is just dummy text. "Test Content"

Comment: Do you have any error in the logs ?

Comment: 2016-02-11T14:15:57+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: block  in /mnt/data/home/43105-34663.cloudwaysapps.com/dfscqmxare/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php on line 197

The above is the only error that I can see in my system.log file. But that is not related to the module I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35588/discussion-between-digital-pianism-and-vickythegme).